# How can i refresh notification count and remove parent when it is deleted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parent-child, removechild

when delete trough ajax call how can remove that content from the view.?

this my ajax call and i am deleting a job from there when it deletes.

1. that parent has to remove and
2. the job notification count has to refresh(MY JOBS (3) it should change as 2 because there are only 2 jobs are there now in db when i logout and login it coming as 2.)

[image: image of deleted job not parent is not deleted.]

Here is my ajax controller code:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['res'])&& ($_POST['res'] =='no'))
{
    $jobId=$_POST['jobId'];
    $updateStatus=$conn->query("UPDATE r_job_invitations SET inv_res='2' WHERE id_job='".$jobId."' ");
    if ($updateStatus) {
        $response['message'] = "<strong>Success!</strong> Job Rejected.";
        $response['success'] = true;
        } else {
        $response['message'] = "<strong>Warning!</strong> There is an error in Job Rejection please try again";
        $response['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

My ajax call and sending request:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default" onclick="jobResponse('no',<?php echo $myjobs['id_job'];?>)">Reject And Delete</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function jobResponse(res,jobId){
        var frm_data = { res : res,
            jobId : jobId
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'inv-controller.php',
            data: frm_data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response["success"] == true)
                {   
                    $("#success-message").show();
                    $("#success-message").html(response["message"]);
                    } else {
                    $("#warning-message").show();
                    $("#warning-message").html(response["message"]);
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#warning-message").show();
                $("#warning-message").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And finally this jobs count session is coming from login controller

while logging in i am stroing that jobs count in a session like this:

```
$Query = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as notificationCount FROM r_job_invitations where email='".$_SESSION['user_email']."' and inv_res=0") or die(mysqli_error());
$notification = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query);     
$_SESSION['notificationCount'] = $notification['notificationCount'];
echo BASE_URL."my-profile.php";
```

I want to update this session count. how can i do that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your ajax controller page:

```
if ($updateStatus) {
    $response['message'] = "<strong>Success!</strong> Job Rejected.";
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['newCount'] = $_SESSION['notificationCount']+1;
    $_SESSION['notificationCount']++;
......
```

and then in your jquery

```
if (response["success"] == true)
            {  
                $("#success-message").show();
                $("#success-message").html(response["message"]);
                $('selector_that_has_your_old_count').html(response["newCount"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting parent class these are the changes i have done:
View & Response:

```
<div class="row" id="jobrow<?php echo $myjobs['id_job'];?>">
$("#jobrow"+jobId).remove();
```

For updating the count:
view page:

```
<span class="badge" id="notificationcount">
```

response:
    if (response["success"] == true)
    {
        $("#success-message").show();
        $("#success-message").html(response["message"]);
        $("#notificationcount").html(response["notificationCount"]);
    }

controller page:

```
$Query = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as notificationCount FROM r_job_invitations where email='".$_SESSION['user_email']."' and inv_res=0") or die(mysqli_error());
$notification = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query);     
$_SESSION['notificationCount'] = $notification['notificationCount'];            

if ($updateStatus) {
    $response['message'] = "<strong>Success!</strong> Job Rejected.";
    $response['notificationCount'] = $_SESSION['notificationCount'];            
    $response['success'] = true;
    } else {
    $response['message'] = "<strong>Warning!</strong> There is an error in Job Rejection please try again";
    $response['success'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
}
```